# Components of a Vector Perpendicular to Itself

Tags: vectors

I have multiple doubts in vectors. They are as follows.

1. Can a vector have components perpendicular to itself?
2. Is the sum of the components (rectangular or non-rectangular) of a vector **a** always equal to it?
3. Can the magnitude of a component of a vector **a** be greater its magnitude?

Doubt no. 3 arose after solving the following problem.

> A vector **a** of magnitude 8 units has two components. One is  perpendicular to **a** and is of magnitude 6 units. What is the magnitude of the other component?

*(Mathematics: Mechanics and Probability, by L. Bostock, Suzanne Chandler, Examples 2a, 2  [see here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=NjeaS1rcFrIC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=A%C2%A0vector%C2%A0a%C2%A0of%C2%A0magnitude%C2%A08%C2%A0units%C2%A0has%C2%A0two%C2%A0components.%C2%A0One%C2%A0is%C2%A0%C2%A0perpendicular%C2%A0to%C2%A0a%C2%A0and%C2%A0is%C2%A0of%C2%A0magnitude6%C2%A0units.%C2%A0What%C2%A0is%C2%A0the%C2%A0magnitude%C2%A0of%C2%A0the%C2%A0other%C2%A0component?&source=bl&ots=jQXYcGsLGQ&sig=ACfU3U2Gpy-vAHtIIiSCIuGyc-pwIbDTRQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcssKA8YXpAhXGT30KHXp1DwwQ6AEwEXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=A%C2%A0vector%C2%A0a%C2%A0of%C2%A0magnitude%C2%A08%C2%A0units%C2%A0has%C2%A0two%C2%A0components.%C2%A0One%C2%A0is%C2%A0%C2%A0perpendicular%C2%A0to%C2%A0a%C2%A0and%C2%A0is%C2%A0of%C2%A0magnitude6%C2%A0units.%C2%A0What%C2%A0is%C2%A0the%C2%A0magnitude%C2%A0of%C2%A0the%C2%A0other%C2%A0component%3F&f=false))*

The author gives **10 units** as it's answers.

Comment: This is really a math question, may be better to ask on Math Stack Exchange?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Is this a high school book? The whole approach to vectors seems odd. The geometry $\vec{AB}, \vec{CD}$ thing, the terms "free" and "tied" vector, and, though more standard, but an annoyance to me: calling $\bf  \hat x$ by the name $\bf i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If by perpendicularity of the component you mean that the dot product between the whole vector, and the vector, formed with only one non-zero component - $a_i$, it can be orthogonal if the dot product is degenerate, i.e for some non-zero vectors holds $(e_i, e_i) = 0$.

The answer for the second question is yes, by definition of vector, it is linear in components.

If the metric (the scalar product) is not positive definite (3) is possible. For example, assume the dot product is  $$(a, b) = a_1 b_1 - a_2 b_2$$
In that case the magnitude of the first component $a_1^2$ is less or equal than the whole magnitude $a_1^2 - a_2^2$.

Answer (score 6):

You can think of a vector as an arrow:

[image: arrow]

The length of the arrow is the magnitude of the vector, and the direction of the arrow is the direction of the vector.

Any vector can be written as a sum of two other vectors:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{V} = \boldsymbol{V}_1 + \boldsymbol{V}_2
\end{equation}
Then, $\boldsymbol{V}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{V}_2$ are called *components* of the vector $\boldsymbol{V}$.

Now, let's go back to the picture of an arrow. Start from the end of the arrow:

1. Draw another arrow, pointing in any direction, and with any magnitude.
2. From the tip of the second arrow, draw a third arrow, and connect it to the tip of the first arrow.

You get something like this:

[image: vector triangle]

The two arrows you've drawn are component vectors of the first arrow!

---

With this out of the way, let's look at your specific questions.

> 1) Can a vector have components perpendicular to itself?

Perpendicular means that the angle between the vectors are $90^\mathrm{o}$. This one should be easy to answer for yourself, so try it: following the steps above, can you draw a triangle of arrows, with at least one of the component arrows being $90^\mathrm{o}$ to the first arrow?

> 2) Is the sum of the components (rectangular or non-rectangular) of a vector a always equal to it?

Yes! That is what "component" means, after all.

> 3) Can the magnitude of a component of a vector a be greater its magnitude?

Yes! Here's an example:

[image: vector triangle 2]

Now... try the problem from the book again, and see if you're able to find the correct answer. Good luck :-)

And I hope you don't mind my shoddy MS Paint images :-)

Answer (score 3):

> I have multiple doubts in vectors.

This appears to be due to using a very strange book. The book you are using is introducing you to non-orthonormal bases, which is a more advanced topic that I personally do not feel is appropriate at the high school level.

> 1) Can a vector have components perpendicular to itself?

Not in a standard orthonormal basis, but in a non orthonormal basis, yes.

> 2) Is the sum of the components (rectangular or non-rectangular) of a vector a always equal to it?

Yes, regardless of if the basis is orthonormal or not the sum of a vector’s components is the vector. It appears from context that you are using the term “rectangular” to refer to an orthonormal basis and “non-rectangular” to refer to a non-orthonormal basis

> 3) Can the magnitude of a component of a vector a be greater its magnitude?

Yes, but only in a non-orthonormal basis. In a standard orthonormal basis (rectangular) the vector magnitude will always be greater than or equal to the magnitudes of each component.

In the problem you worked, since one of the basis vectors was perpendicular to $\mathbf a$ and nonzero, that automatically implies that the basis is non-orthonormal (non-rectangular). Once you recognize that, then solving the problem is simply a matter of applying the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: I don't use this book. I was just solving some practice problems given by my institute. While tracing the originality of this question, I happened to come across this book. Anyway, Thank you very much, Dale. I really appreciate the way you have described it... I owe you very much :)